# try except strange behavior python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-catch, except

I'm a little confused why an input of `'2'` to the `raw_input` prompt still gives not int error after eval (see code below)

```
correctInput = False

while not correctInput:
    try:
        raw_n = raw_input('Enter a non-negative number: ')
        print raw_n, 'before eval'
        n = eval(raw_n)
        print n, 'after eval'
    except NameError:
        print 'Wrong entry (NameError) ... try again'
    except SyntaxError:
        print 'Wrong entry (SyntaxError) ... try again'
    except NotImplementedError:
        print 'Wrong entry (NotImplementedError) ... try again'
    else:
        if type(n) != int:
            print 'Wrong entry (not int) ... try again'
        else:
            print 'Correct input'
            correctInput = True
```

The output looks like:

```
Enter a non-negative number: '2'
'2' before eval
2 after eval
Wrong entry (not int) ... try again
Enter a non-negative number: 3
3 before eval
3 after eval
Correct input
```

However, if I check on terminal

```
>>> x = eval('2')
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(x) == int
True
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Could not replicate; that works fine for me. Although it's very complicated: `try: int(raw_input(...)); except ValueError:` does the same thing with less messing around. Also, prefer `ininstance(n, int)` (or even `type(n) is int`; `int` is a singleton) to `type(n) == int`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter `'2'` at the `raw_input` prompt - literally apostrophe, 2, apostrophe - you don't get the 1-character string `'2'`, as you would if you typed that into Python source code. You get a string whose contents are the 3 characters apostrophe, 2, apostrophe. `eval` evaluates that as Python source code, producing the string `'2'`.

Instead of typing `'2'`, type `2`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the behavior. Indeed the `len()` of the raw_input is `3`